# Get the value from module to template

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I want to pass the value from module to page tpl file in drupal.I have created a custom module 'one_time_popup'.I have created a sample soutput and tried to pass it and print in page.tpl.php after footer section.but doesn't shows any thing.What I did wrong.I'm a newbie

```
function one_time_popup_menu(){
$items['oneTimePopupData'] = array(
'title' => 'One time Popup',
'page callback' => 'one_time_popup_user_login',
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
'access callback' => TRUE,
);
return $items;
}
function one_time_popup_user_login(&$edit, $account){
 ...
$output='value from one time popup module!';
return theme('photo_order',array('results' => $output));
} 
function one_time_popup_theme() {
 return array(
'photo_order' => array(
  'template' => 'page',
  'variables' => array(
    'results' => NULL,
  ),
 ),
 ); 
}

Tpl file(page.tpl)
<?php echo $results; ?>
```

Comment: I think your page.tpl file should be renamed  in page.tpl.php.
I've tried your code and it seems to work with page.tpl.php.

Comment: Is it workings only in project/oneTimePopupData

Comment: I tried this and two things you need to have page arguments set in `$items` array and second of all you are passing `$edit` by reference. Removing the `&` will work. Although I would suggest you to read https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24135/parameter-expected-to-be-reference-value-given-error-in-menu-page-callback/24139#24139

Comment: can you give example

Comment: use preprocess template_preprocess_page()

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
function one_time_popup_menu(){
    $items['popuppage'] = array(
        'title' => 'One time Popup',
        'page callback' => 'one_time_popup_page',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );
    return $items;
}

function one_time_popup_page(){
    $output = 'value from one time popup module!';
    return theme('photo_order',array('results' => $output));
}

function one_time_popup_theme() {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'one_time_popup');
    return array(
        'photo_order' => array(
            'variables' => array('results' => null),
            'template' => 'photo_order',
            'path' => $path, 
        ),
    );
}
```

Place your tpl file **photo_order.tpl.php** in your module directory and inside it use the below code.

```
<?php print $results; ?>
```

or

```
function one_time_popup_theme() {
    return array(
        'photo_order' => array(
            'variables' => array('results' => null),
            'template' => 'photo_order',
        ),
    );
}
```

Place your tpl file **photo_order.tpl.php** in your theme directory and inside it place the below code

```
<?php print $results; ?>
```

Go to your http://yourdomain.com/popuppage to see the result.